# Code Merging with offshore team - different source control repositories

Tags: merge, automation, git-merge

Summary:

We used to be on SVN and working with offshore team building our automation.
We periodically merged to keep us in sync(local and offshore team). Like every other day or so.
Local team switched to GIT while offshore continued their work on SVN. Security policies, still flushing out new git processes and such...
We have 2 different projects now that are off sync.

Question:
Now that we want them to move to GIT so that we can sync up I can think of couple of options once their code is in GIT:

1. Manual merge (its been a month, but I think I can do it). Manually copy files over, build fix etc.
2. Have offshore team rename their files a little so that GIT thinks its a new file and then manually resolve some duplicates perhaps. 
   There shouldn't be many

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that git can use a svn upstream?! You can just pull their changes. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client . Also, who decided on going separate paths without a defined merge strategy?

Comment: It doesn't matter at this point who's fault it is. We are trying to find the best solution here after the fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual merge should be a straightforward solution:

Compare and merge two different folders, one with your Git repo, one with the latest SVN HEAD revision.
Once the merge is done, you can send them back a [Git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) (one file), which they can clone and start working from, within their own Git cloned repo.